# Не листаются слайды

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

Не могу разобраться со слайдером, взял исходник не помню где, переделал под себя, вроде работал, выпилил кнопку назад - умер, возвратом кнопки ничего не решилось

```js
var divSlideArray = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
  divArrowRight = document.querySelector('.arrow-right'),
  currentSlide = 0;

divArrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() 

  divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
  divSlideArray[++currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

  if (currentSlide == divSlideArray.length - 1) {
    divArrowRight.style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
  }

});
```

```css
.wrap-slider {
  position: relative;
}

#form-slider {
  width: auto;
}

#form-slider .slide {
  margin: 15% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#form-slider .slide:first-child~.slide {
  display: none;
}

#slider-arrows [class^="arrow"] {
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4991e3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  margin: -20px 40px 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-left {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-right {
  float: right;
}

.slide {
  color: #fff;
  background: #494949;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-slider">
  <form id="form-slider" action="" method="post">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/000000" class="pic1">

      <div id="slider-arrows">
        <!--<div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>-->
        <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/000000/ff00ff" class="pic1">

      <div id="slider-arrows">
        <!--<div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>-->
        <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="radio">
        <p>Ваше имя<br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"></p>
        <p>Ваш email<br><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш email"></p>
        <p>Ваш телефон<br><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+7XXXXXXXXXX"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Не могу разобраться со слайдером, взял исходник не помню где, переделал под себя, вроде работал, выпилил кнопку назад - умер, возвратом кнопки ничего не решилось

Пропустили скобку в `if`.

```js
var divSlideArray = document.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
  divArrowRight = document.querySelectorAll('.arrow-right'),
  currentSlide = 0;
//----------------------------------------------------------------
// Проходим по массиву  
divArrowRight.forEach(function(e) {
  // Вешаем событие
  e.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    divSlideArray[currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'none', '');
    divSlideArray[++currentSlide].style.setProperty('display', 'block', '');

    //----------------------------------------------------------------
    
    if (currentSlide == divSlideArray.length - 1) { /// <------ Missing {
      e.target.style.display = 'none';
    }

  });
})
```

```css
.wrap-slider {
  position: relative;
}

#form-slider {
  width: auto;
}

#form-slider .slide {
  margin: 15% auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#form-slider .slide:first-child~.slide {
  display: none;
}

#slider-arrows [class^="arrow"] {
  user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /******************** added ********************/
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #4991e3;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  padding: 15px 60px;
  margin: -20px 40px 40px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-left {
  display: none;
  left: 0;
}

#slider-arrows .arrow-right {
  float: right;
}

.slide {
  color: #fff;
  background: #494949;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/******************** added ********************/

.show {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap-slider">
  <form id="form-slider" action="" method="post">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/300" class="pic1">


      <div id="slider-arrows">
        <!--<div class="arrow-left">Назад</div>-->
        <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="slide">
      <img src="//picsum.photos/200/301" class="pic1">

      <div id="slider-arrows">
        <!-- <div class="arrow-left">Назад</div> -->
        <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="arrow-right">Вперед</div>

    <div class="slide">
      <div class="radio">
        <p>Ваше имя<br><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя"></p>
        <p>Ваш email<br><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Ваш email"></p>
        <p>Ваш телефон<br><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="+7XXXXXXXXXX"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="save"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Помогло, но дальше, чем на 1 слайд не листается

Comment: @Dvst8d обновил, если вообще правильно вас понял, коменты в коде.

Comment: Нет, это не много не то. Вы сделали смену картинки, что мне не много не подходит, сначала делался квиз, и должен бы листаться слайдами, но для большей конкретизации вопроса выпилил большое кол-во кода. Вот весь: https://jsfiddle.net/uxg4dktq/

Comment: @Dvst8d у вас несколько кнопок Вперед, а вешаете вы события только на первую, вот и получается что дальше первой у вас слайды не листаются.

Comment: А как это исправить? Записать функцию и на onclick прибить ко всем кнопкам? Или есть более верный вариант?

Comment: @Dvst8d добавил, код.